# Releasing a Com Object

Tags: c#, com, interop, release

Which is more correct way to relase a com object, type 1 or type 2 or doesn't matter? (_**document** is an **interface**)

```
    private IHTMLDocument2 _document;


    public HtmlDocument()
    {
        _document = new HTMLDocumentClass();
    }

    private void DisposeUnmanagedResources1()
    {
        if (_document != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_document);
            _document = null;
        }
    }

    private void DisposeUnmanagedResources2()
    {
        if (_document != null)
        {
            var doc = ((HTMLDocumentClass) _document);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
            doc = null;
            _document = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DisposeUnmanagedResources1()` seems like it would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

The correct thing to do is to **do nothing** - the .Net framework will take care of decrementing the reference count when the object is no longer reachable.

In fact there are a couple of reasons why you **shouldn't** call `ReleaseComObject` - firstly because the COM object might in fact be a managed COM object, in which case the call to `ReleaseComObject` will fail, and secondly because other managed components might have a reference to `_document` that they are still using. (Probably not in your example, but quite possible in other cases)

See [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx) for more information.

**Update:** BrendanMcKs answer has a couple of interesting articles on why you might want to explicitly call `ReleaseComObject` in certain situations (typically server applications) to release COM objects as soon as possible for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The cast doesn't do anything here. It's still the same object. `ReleaseComObject`'s signature takes an `object`, so it will just get an object reference anyway.

Internally `Marshall.ReleaseComObject` is just going to decrement its reference count. The runtime will then release the native object if its ref count hits zero and the wrapper will get killed off. Over here on the managed side of things you don't have much influence.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer here is: neither. The CLR takes care of releasing COM objects for you; you should only use Marshal.ReleaseComObject if you absolutely need to take explicit control over the releasing; eg. to release specific objects in a specific order. These tend to be somewhat  advanced cases. Most normal code should just let the GC do its thing.

Also note that ReleaseComObject doesn't map directly to IUnknown::Release() - check out [this article from Chris Brumme on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/16/51355.aspx) for more details about how it works and when to use it. More background on the type of case where you'd want to use ReleaseComObject at [this Visual Studio blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2006/09/20/762884.aspx).